# select and update grant privilege oracle

Tags: oracle, select, sql-grant

I am trying to grant an user privilege to update on specific columns using the where clause.
Based on what I have learnt, in order to update using where once must have SELECT privileges.
This is what I have and I know the syntax is wrong so could you please tell me the correct syntax or where to find it?

```
grant  select, update on
fullname, address where empid>5 to updateruser;
```

then I tried this
grant select, update (empid, fullname) on 
myemployee to updateruser where empid>105;

Comment: I got the answer! It was easy. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.
Although You could create a View on your table:

```
create view table_view as select fullname, address from base_table where empid > 5;
```

and then grant access to this view:

```
grant select, update on table_view to updateuser;
```

this should work since such simple view is updatable in oracle.